error compilation Latex code on mac os
I don't know where to put my personal files to compile Latex under Mac OS Sonoma. I have a file mycmds.tex and optics.sty? I created a texmf directory in library where I placed my files, but when I compile I get an error message: ""
I use Mactex 2024
  Message
Error line 1 I can'tfind file mycmds.tex".|iput mycmds.tex
Error line 1 ! Emergeney stop.\input mycmds.tex
 Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!


I checked the post in question. I already have the texmf folder in my library, and my .tex and .sty files are in that folder, and I still have the same problem. Should I install the font? I didn't understand that point.

The texmf folder needs to be organized in the way outlined in that question. So optics.sty needs to be in ~/Library/texmf/tex/latex; it's not enough to just put it inside ~/Library/texmf. Did you do that?  Or use the helper app linked in my answer.

Thank you , I solved the problem by following your advice
